# Rewrite folder to subdomain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite all addresses after this

`http://example.com/users/*`

to this

`http://*.example.com/`

for example:

`http://example.com/users/admin`

`http://admin.example.com/`

I want to do this in a .htaccess file.

I now have this, but it dont work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/?$ http://$1.example.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: as i understood, you don't need to  redirect `http://example.com/users/*` to `http://*.example.com/` , you need when a user go to `http://*.example.com/` without changing url or redirecting to another page show the content of `http://example.com/users/*`. is it your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot before the domain in the `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/?$ http://$1.example.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Your rule is failing because you are checking against `http://example.com`, not matching the starting dot.

Comment: it work but i dont see my index.html How can i fix that?

Comment: @Joachim what do you mean by "I dont see my index.html"? It gives you errors? What is your folder structure? Where is your index.html located?

Comment: i have a index.html located at http://example.com/users/admin and i will see it at http://admin.example.com/ but i dont see it.

Comment: @Joachim as you are _redirecting_ your users to `admin.example.com`, make sure that you correctly configured the `VirtualHost` in Apache to serve that request. Anyway, this question is about rewriting an URL with `mod-rewrite`, so this should be another question.