# How to redirect to subdomain from subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect from mysite.com/articles/**article-name** to **article-name**.mysite.com

At this moment I am working on XAMPP, is it even possible to do on it?

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^articles/([^-]*)$ showArticle.php?id=$1
```

Comment: You could setup rewrite to direct all requests to an "index.php" page and then have that read the URL and redirect as needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite folder to subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463736/rewrite-folder-to-subdomain). Since you don't seem to be using "www.", also see [Rewrite folder to subdomain with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278191/rewrite-folder-to-subdomain-with-htaccess).